# c function executes repeatedly without being called, causes segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sdl, sdl-2

I have been following LazyFoo's SDL2 tutorials and modifying the code slightly so i can compile it as C code on Linux (I am a C programmer and don't know much C++). In the [second tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php) he splits his code up into four functions: `init()` which handles all the initialization, `loadMedia()` which loads an image, `close()` which frees all the memory up at the end, and `main()`.

My issue is that partway through the `init()` function (just after `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` is called), `close()` is called repeatedly (181 times) before executing the rest of `init()`. `close()` then runs a couple more times before the program segfaults.

My modifications to the code are as follows:

- Changing `#include <SDL.h>` to `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`
- `include <stdbool.h>`, as is required by C
- Changing the file extension to .c from .cpp
- The addition of a while loop for the rendering portion of the program in `main()`:

  ```
  SDL_Event event;
  int quit = false;
  while( !quit ) {
      SDL_WaitEvent( &event );
      if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
          quit = true;
      }
      //Apply the image
      SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );
      //Update the surface
      SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
  }
  ```

  This is to fix an issue I had with the first tutorial where nothing was being drawn to the window
- Removal of the line `SDL_Delay( 2000 );` because it isn't necessary with the rendering loop
- Changing the path to the .bmp file from `02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/hello_.bmp` to `hello.bmp` because the source and the image are located in the same folder

I have found that the error occurs even if I remove the call to `close()`, but runs fine if I remove the function altogether. It also runs fine if I leave the file extension as .cpp, although as far as I'm aware none of the code uses C++ specific features. It might be worth noting that the a window is successfully created, but nothing is ever drawn to it. I'm really at a loss here as to what the cause of it all is.

I compiled the code using GCC V6.3.0 on a Debian Stretch installation. The original source is available for download at the page linked above. My modified version is below.

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2015)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

//Loads media
bool loadMedia();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

//The image we will load and show on the screen
SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld = NULL;

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    //Loading success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Load splash image
    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP( "hello_world.bmp" );
    if( gHelloWorld == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    //Deallocate surface
    SDL_FreeSurface( gHelloWorld );
    gHelloWorld = NULL;

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Load media
        if( !loadMedia() )
        {
            printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            SDL_Event event;
            int quit = false;
            while( !quit ) {
                SDL_WaitEvent( &event );
                if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
                    quit = true;
                }
                //Apply the image
                SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

                //Update the surface
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
            }
        }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If changing the file extension makes the code behave differently then you're not running what you think you are running...

Comment: the function: `close()` is a well known C library function.  Your code should not be using C library function names for your local function names.

Comment: regarding the prototype: `bool init();`  when a function takes no parameters, the prototype must have `void` between the parens. I.E. `bool init( void );` Similar considerations exist for the prototypes: `bool loadMedia();` and `void close();`

Comment: When a parameter to a function is not going to be used, then either eliminate the parameter (I.E. `int main( void )` ) or the first line(s) in the body of the function need to be cast to `void`  I.E. `int main( int argc, char **argv ) { (void)argc; (void)argv;`

Comment: When compiling as C++ you can have one `bool close();` and one [`int close(int);`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/close.html) as overloads. In C you can only have one function named `close`. That's also one reason for all the `SDL_`-prefixes - to make the names unique.

Comment: regarding: `printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError() );`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr,  "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError() );`

Comment: If `init()` fails, do you really want to be calling `close()`?  I doubt it.

Comment: regarding: ` while( !quit )
            {
                SDL_WaitEvent( &event );
                if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
                //Apply the image
                SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

                //Update the surface
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
            }`  if the `event` is `SDL_QUIT` then probably should NOT be calling: `SDL_BlitSurface()` nor `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface()`  Suggest using a `else` for those statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close` is an operating system function that closes a file handle (an open file, or a socket, or just about anything).

You have defined your own function called `close`, and your own functions take priority over library functions. Every time something wants to close a file handle, it calls your `close` function. (And also the file handle doesn't get closed because the real `close` function wasn't called).